# Selenium - Remote Control - Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remote-control

When I start the selenium test with gird (Remote control), I see this ERROR on log. The browser is not able to open. I did check and tried the following things:

- Stop and start both hub and node. I use the default commands to start hub and node. From command prompt, I see that the node was registered successfully and ready to use
- Clean Eclipse Project at Project>Clean
- Restart my PC
- Disconnect VPN
- Use latest selenium standalone 3.6; chromedriver.exe
- Check the path to chromedriver.exe
- Use my PC as hub and another PC as node

Please note that this issue only happen if I run the test with grid (remote control). The test can run normally locally.

```
2017-10-20 15:23:37,805 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method OpenBrowser | Exception desc : Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'MY-PC', ip: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 319 milliseconds
```

Please give me advice in this case. Thanks!